# Sidebar Item List Padding Overlapping Eachother?

Tags: html, css

I am just learning how to code in HTML and CSS so don't get mad at me if I code outdated or weirdly to you. Anyways, I'm trying to make a simple test website with a sidebar and I am stuck on it because my item list has padding that causes each item to overlap eachother.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/w82akt0v/

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!--Default Stuff-->
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <title>Abyss</title>

    <!--Script Links-->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script src="js/script.js"></script>

    <!--Stylesheet Links-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" text="text/css" href="css/style.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" text="text/css" href="css/font-awesome.min.css">

    <!--Font Links-->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
    <!--Website Sidebar-->
    <div id="sidebar">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
```

**CSS:**

```
/* Default Stuff */
body {
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
font-family:"Open Sans", sans-serif;
}

/* Website Sidebar */
#sidebar {
background:rgb(41,41,41);
width:180px;
height:100%;
position:absolute;
left:0px;
top:0px;
}

ul {
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
}

ul li {
list-style:none;
}

ul li a {
background:rgb(41,41,41);
color:#ccc;
border-bottom:2px solid #111;
width:160px;
padding:10px;
text-decoration:none;
}

ul li:before {
content:'\f1ce';
font-family:'FontAwesome';
}
```

Comment: add ul li a{display:block;}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the padding of `a` tag and add to `li`

```
ul li {
  list-style: outside none none;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

try with snippet

```css
body {
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
font-family:"Open Sans", sans-serif;
}

/* Website Sidebar */
#sidebar {
background:rgb(41,41,41);
width:180px;
height:100%;
position:absolute;
left:0px;
top:0px;
}

ul {
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
}

ul li {
list-style:none;
  padding:15px;
  border-bottom:2px solid #111;
  display: block;
}

ul li a {
background:rgb(41,41,41);
color:#ccc;

width:160px;
text-decoration:none;
}

ul li:before {
content:'\f1ce';
font-family:'FontAwesome';
}
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script src="js/script.js"></script>

    <!--Stylesheet Links-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" text="text/css" href="css/style.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" text="text/css" href="css/font-awesome.min.css">

    <!--Font Links-->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
    <!--Website Sidebar-->
    <div id="sidebar">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Ok so I tries them all and adding padding to ul li instead of ul li a worked. The only problem is that now my underline is only under the word and I want to keep it how it used to be, under the whole thing.

Comment: No I want to keep the underline so you can tell where the link tab closes off. I want it ass before so it was across the whole bottom.

Comment: please check  now , don't forgot to tick the answer if its worked for you

Answer (score 0):

Add display:block; to anchor tag, it will take your given padding.

```
ul li a{display:block;}
```

Here is snippet for the same

```css
/* Default Stuff */
body {
 margin:0px;
 padding:0px;
 font-family:"Open Sans", sans-serif;
}

/* Website Sidebar */
#sidebar {
 background:rgb(41,41,41);
 width:180px;
 height:100%;
 position:absolute;
 left:0px;
 top:0px;
}

ul {
 margin:0px;
 padding:0px;
}

ul li {
 list-style:none;
}

ul li a {
 background:rgb(41,41,41);
 color:#ccc;
 border-bottom:2px solid #111;
 width:160px;
 padding:10px;
 text-decoration:none;
  display:block;
}

ul li:before {
 content:'\f1ce';
 font-family:'FontAwesome';
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <!--Default Stuff-->
  <title>Abyss</title>

  <!--Script Links-->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script src="js/script.js"></script>

  <!--Stylesheet Links-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" text="text/css" href="css/style.css">

  <link rel="stylesheet" text="text/css" href="css/font-awesome.min.css">

  <!--Font Links-->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
 </head>

 <body>
  <!--Website Sidebar-->
  <div id="sidebar">
   <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give `line-height:30px` to #sidebar

```css
/* Default Stuff */
body {
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
font-family:"Open Sans", sans-serif;
}

/* Website Sidebar */
#sidebar {
background:rgb(41,41,41);
width:180px;
height:100%;
position:absolute;
left:0px;
top:0px;
line-height:30px;
}

ul {
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
}

ul li {
list-style:none;
  padding:15px
}

ul li a {
background:rgb(41,41,41);
color:#ccc;
border-bottom:2px solid #111;
width:160px;
text-decoration:none;
}

ul li:before {
content:'\f1ce';
font-family:'FontAwesome';
}
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script src="js/script.js"></script>

    <!--Stylesheet Links-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" text="text/css" href="css/style.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" text="text/css" href="css/font-awesome.min.css">

    <!--Font Links-->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
    <!--Website Sidebar-->
    <div id="sidebar">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
```